# SML type inference by hand

Tags: sml, type-inference

Hello I am getting ready for my finals and there is always ml type inference on the exams . 
i.e. we are asked to write the type of a function like this one :

```
fun ugh x y z = x z (y z);
val ugh = fn : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c
```

or

```
fun doh x y z = z (x y ) (y + 1);
val doh = fn : (int -> 'a) -> int -> ('a -> int -> 'b) -> 'b
```

However all the ways I am trying to infer the type I always get it wrong . 
Although there are examples online there are no examples for functions like that . 
Is there a way to make up the type following some guidelines  ?
The guidelines would be best if applied to the first example .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several examples of type inference by hand on StackOverflow: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640686/hint-for-sml-type-inference), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575458/how-to-draw-a-type-inference-parse-tree-for-sml), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246473/how-does-the-compiler-determine-types-in-sml), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594801/sml-church-numeral-type-inference), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490025/questions-on-sml-type-ckecking-and-inference), ...

1. To infer the type of `fun ugh x y z = x z (y z)`, you could start by saying that

   ```
   val ugh : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd
   ```

   since it takes three curried arguments. You can also see that `x : 'a` is a function of two curried parameters and that `y : 'b` is a function of one parameter, and that `'d` should be expressed entirely in terms of `'a`, `'b` and `'c`.

   So for the type of `y`, set `'b = 'c -> 'e`, since it takes `z : 'c` as input and returns something of a type that we haven't gotten to yet.

   And for the type of `x`, set `'a = 'c -> 'e -> 'f`, since it takes `z : 'c` and the output of `y` as input and returns something of a type that we haven't gotten to yet.

   Replacing those, adding parentheses as needed, you get

   ```
   val ugh : ('c -> 'e -> 'f) -> ('c -> 'e) -> 'c -> 'f
   ```

   At that point you might want to rename them so you get

   ```
   val ugh : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c
   ```

   but you don't really have to.

   The only things I had to think about here was the fact that the type of `x` depends on the type of `y`, so I wanted to determine that first.

---

2. To infer the type of `fun doh x y z = z (x y) (y + 1)`, you could similarly start by saying that

   ```
   val doh : 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd
   ```

   since it also takes three curried arguments. Most easily you can set `'b = int`, and similar to the first example, you can set `'a = int -> 'e` and then `'c = 'e -> int -> 'd`.

   Replacing those, adding parentheses as needed, you get

   ```
   val doh : (int -> 'e) -> int -> ('e -> int -> 'd) -> 'd
   ```

   or after a little renaming

   ```
   val doh : (int -> 'a) -> int -> ('a -> int -> 'b) -> 'b
   ```

Comment: The way you set 'c = int and 'b int -> 'e the type should be : 
val doh : ('e -> int -> 'd) ->  (int -> 'e) -> int  -> 'd .
What troubles me more is the correct order of those types . Starting from left to right do we put the arguments in order that they appear on the left of the function , meaning that x->y->z->doh ?

Comment: Plus the compiler gives this type for doh : (int -> 'a) -> int -> ('a -> int -> 'b) -> 'b

Comment: You swapped the positions of the `'a` and `'c` substitutions in that last result.

Comment: @Akismpa: You could try with the order they appear on the screen. In the first example, though, the function `x` takes the output of function `y` as input, and since I haven't expressed the type of `y` as a function from one type to another yet, I can't readily expand the type of `x` in terms of that. So I put `x` on hold and started inferring `y` instead. You might end up with mutual dependencies or large enough examples that following a type inference algorithm strictly will be a benefit. But as long as you can keep track of the variables in your head, there doesn't seem to be a need to me.